# Javamail get CC from Gmail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, carbon-copy

```
if ((a = m.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC)) != null) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {

    InternetAddress ia = (InternetAddress)a[j];
    if (ia.isGroup()) {
        InternetAddress[] aa = ia.getGroup(false);
        for (int k = 0; k < aa.length; k++) {
                    cc.append(aa[k].getAddress()).append("; ");
                }
    }
            else
            {
                cc.append(ia.getAddress()).append("; ");
            }

    }
}
```

Hello I use Javamail to get CC adresses, but when I invoke getRecipients() from message object i got null. With recipient type TO it works. I get mail from Gmail, and on 100 percent message have CC adresses. It was a bug? Maybe I do it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaMail returns what the server tells it.  Turn on the [protocol trace](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) to see what the server is returning to JavaMail.  The Cc information will be in the ENVELOPE response from the IMAP server.